# How is this a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

This is a question I’ve seen posed here before, but I want to tackle the problem with a different definition in mind.

The question is as follows:

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables, show that $U$ is as well, given

$U({\omega})=X({\omega})+Y({\omega})$.

The definition I want to use is this:

A discrete random variable $X$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P} )$ is a mapping $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ such that

(i) $X(\Omega)$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and

(ii) $\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)=x\}\in\mathscr{F}$, for all $x\in X(\Omega)$

Condition (i) is easy for me to check. The part I am lost on is how to prove condition (ii). How do I show that $\{\omega\in\Omega : U(\omega)=u\}\in\mathscr{F}$, for all $u\in U(\Omega)$?

Comment: @copper.hat It isn’t given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually write

$$\{\omega\in\Omega: U(\omega)=u\}=\bigcup_{x\in X(\Omega)}(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x\}\cap(\{\omega\in\Omega: Y(\omega)=u-x\}))$$

which is a countable union of events in $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: It should not be a union on the RHS of the equality but an intersection.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Corrected that.